# Grab specific JSON Object and print them

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

The goal is to write all the names for each id. Here is an example of the JSON file. Also, If you could help me re-word the title of the question.

```
"AllStudents":
        {
                "id": "1"
                "properties":{
                       "Classes":[{
                                "name" = "math",
                                "Grades":[{
                                           "value" = "80"},
                                           "value" = "60"}]
                                "name"= "Chemistry",
                                "Grades":[{
                                           "value" = "100"},
                                           "value" = "15"}]
                "id": "2"
                "properties":{
                       "Classes":[{
                                "name" = "physics",
                                "Grades":[{
                                           "value" = "50"},
                                           "value" = "10"}]
                                "name"= "Computer",
                                "Grades":[{
                                           "value" = "20"},
                                           "value" = "60"}]
```

Current Code:

```
with open("students.json") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    jsonData = data["AllStudents"]
    for distro in jsonData:
        printID = distro['id']            
        x = " ".join(name['name'] for name in distro['properties']['channels'])
        for channel in distro['properties']['channels']:
            y = " ".join(str(name['value']) for name in channel['Grades'])
            print(PrintID, x, y)
```

> Output Im getting with the current code is this:
>
> 1, math, chemisty, 80, 60
>
> 1, math, chemistry, 100, 15
>
> 2, physics, computer, 50, 10
>
> 2, physics, computer, 20, 60

The issue with my current code is that it only prints the first name which is math. How do I make it so that it prints every single name for each id?

> Output I want:
>
> 1, math, 80, 60, chemistry, 100, 15
>
> 2, physics, 50, 10, computer, 20, 60

Comment: Like most JSON questions on Stack Overflow, this doesn't have anything to do with JSON. `json.load` returns an ordinary Python `dict`. Your example JSON file isn't valid, though; where did the `=`s come from?

Comment: @HampusLarsson The duplicate keys *is* valid JSON, though by default Python decodes a JSON object to a `dict`, which discards the duplicate keys. If this is the issue, that can be solved using the `object_pairs_hook` in `json.load`.

Comment: (I rescind my previous comment about this not having anything to do with JSON until a valid JSON file is provided.)

Comment: Hi @chepner, I apologize. I'm new to JSON. But isn't the example I gave a JSON file?

Comment: No, it's not. `json.load` could not parse what you posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
with open("students.json") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    jsonData = data["AllStudents"]
    for distro in jsonData:
        concat = f"{distro['id']}, " + ", ".join(name['name'] for name in distro['properties']['Classes'])
        print(concat)
```

Comment: Hey Daniel. Thank you for the help. I updated the question/code and was hoping if you can help me fix this issue I'm having.